# Couchbase lite Documents Save Format

Tags: android, couchbase-lite

We are creating the Documents on couch base lite i need to know the format of document which stores in database to sync to server on mobile devices for example.

We create simple document:

```
com.couchbase.lite.Document document = database.createDocument();

 Map<String, Object> docContent = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    docContent.put("message", "Hello Couchbase Lite 1");
    docContent.put("name", "raheel");
    docContent.put("lastUpdated", this.date());
```

and then put the Document properties:

```
try {
    document.putProperties(docContent);
} catch (CouchbaseLiteException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

so how the data is stored in that document ? in what format?

Answer (score 0):

Couchbase stores the data in JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

This will do just fine, no need for the hashmap

```
document.Put("message", "Hello Couchbase Lite 1");
```